# Passing data from socketcommunication to User Interface

Tags: vb.net, sockets

In my current project I'm sending and receiving textmessages to/from a serversocket/clientsocket (TCP), much like a chat (My project is written in VB.NET). This works as long as I'm converting the bytes sent into strings and presenting them in a msgbox(). 
This code handles that part:

```
Try
    client = ar.AsyncState
    client.EndReceive(ar)
    client.BeginReceive(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnRecieve), client)
    Try
        Dim message As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes2)
        MsgBox(message)
        Array.Clear(bytes2, bytes2.GetLowerBound(0), bytes2.Length)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error writing received message")
    End Try
 Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error receiving message from server")
 End Try
```

So far so good. However when I try to change "MsgBox(message)" into label1.text = message I get the error: "Error writing received message". My questions, then, is why this happens and what can I do to correct it so that I can have my sockets receiving information that can be added to textboxes and other things in the UI?

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a delegate and BeginInvoke() to properly marshal the call to the main UI thread:

```
Private Sub OnRecieve(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        client = ar.AsyncState
        client.EndReceive(ar)

        Try
            Dim message As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes2)
            NewMessage(message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error writing received message")
        Finally
            Array.Clear(bytes2, bytes2.GetLowerBound(0), bytes2.Length)
        End Try

        client.BeginReceive(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnRecieve), client)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error receiving message from server")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub MessageDelegate(ByVal msg As String)

Private Sub NewMessage(ByVal msg As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New MessageDelegate(AddressOf NewMessage), New Object() {msg})
    Else
        Label1.Text = msg
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: OK thanks so much Idle_Mind, I will try this tomorrow and get back to you with the results. I'm relieved that the fix could be fairly simple, so I can get back to my project that has been halted a lot by this.

Comment: Though I'm not aware of what exacly the code does, this seems to be working anyway :) Thanks so much for the help

Comment: You're not supposed to update UI elements from a different thread.  What this does is cause NewMessage() to be run in the UI main thread by using BeginInvoke().  The InvokeRequired line will return true when the control ("Me" = Form) being queried was created on a different thread.  The BeginInvoke() line runs the delegate in the same thread that the control was created on.  This causes a recursive call to the same method where the second run will return false and you drop into the else block where it is safe to update the UI.